# How to securely store password for use by mount

Tags: mount, password, fstab, non-root-user

I would like non-root users to be able to mount certain drives on the local network (or have them be mounted automatically on log-in). To mount network drives (via cifs) a password is passed on over the local network to authenticate. I do not want to allow non-root users to see this password. This creates a dilemma: I do not want to store the password in the /etc/fstab file as then non-root users are able to read it. But I need to give users read privileges to the fstab file to allow users to mount the drives.

What would be a secure and sufficiently elegant way (for the user) to go about this?

Comment: Have you considered using sudo or would you prefer this to work without sudo?

Comment: @Edward Could you elaborate? I would prefer not to have to give users root access.

Comment: Sure. You could add mount permissions to the sudoers file for specific users, using the credentials file trick ajgringo619 mentions below. That way, they can mount without discovering the actual passwords.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the username/password for CIFS mounts in a separate file, then reference it in /etc/fstab. Use the **credentials=/path/to/your_password_file** mount option, then create that file like this:

```
username=your_username
password=your_password
```

Save and set the permissions to 600/root:root

Comment: If I do this, users cannot mount drives which require this username and password. (error 13, permission denied opening credentials file)

Comment: You need to give them (restricted) sudo mount rights, see the comment by Edward on the original question.